# fosuser+sonatauser ignore french translations

Tags: fosuserbundle

I am trying to make a custom labels for a customized register form and login form. I use sonatauserbundle and fosuserbundle, my userbundle hetis from SonataUserbundle.

```
<?php
 namespace SCVBook\UserBundle;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

   class SCVBookUserBundle extends Bundle
    {
     /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
     public function getParent()
     {
        return 'SonataUserBundle';
      }
   }
```

here is my config.file

```
framework:
#esi:             ~
translator:      { fallback: fr }
```

I copied  FOSUserBundle.fr.yml to ACME/UserBundle/Resources/translations, but login and register still use the english translation.

here is a line in my login.html.twig

```
 <label for="username"> {{ 'security.login.username'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>
```

it makes changes only when I change FOSUserBundle.en.yml in vendor/friendsofsymfony/.../Ressources/translations/FOSUserBundle.en.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok found, just I forgot in app/parameters.yml  to set locale to locale:fr, for config.yml
just let it as default.

```
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
```